# Unable to reset class variables

Tags: python, macos, class, variables, reset

So I'm a tad new to Python, I've worked a lot with RPG but I've come across a problem when trying to reset or refresh my variables in my Classes.

At the moment when the user successfully flees the monster, entering the next fight with a goblin will result in the goblin sharing the same statistics as the previous one. For example, the user damages Goblin_1 for 5 damage, meaning its health is at 25/30. If the user run away successfully, the next time the user fights a goblin, its starting health will be 25/30.

This problem also carries over to the earned experience and gold given to the user when they kill the monster. I fairly certain that if the variables were reset after the user ran successfully away this would solve all the problems if I just carried it over to also the win condition.

So to put this in short, we have Goblin_1. Goblin_1 gets damaged for 5 hit points, and is now at 25/30. If the user flees, Goblin_2 will override Goblin_1's statistics and not start at 25/30 hit points.

Any help would be fantastic mates.

```
import sys 
import os
import random
import pickle
import time

## Weapons
weapon1 = {"long sword":10}
weapon2 = {"great sword":40}

## Potions
healthpot = {"health potion": 10}

# User Statistics
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.base_attack = 10
        self.gold = 0
        self.pots_health = 0
        self.weap = ["rusty sword"]
        self.curweap = "Rusty Sword"

# Attack Modifiers
    @property 
    def attack(self):
        attack = self.base_attack
        if self.curweap == "rusty sword":
            attack += 2

        if self.curweap == "long sword":
            attack += 10

        if self.curweap == "great sword":
            attack += 20

        return attack

## Monsters
class Goblin:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 30
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(3,8)
        self.goldgain = random.randint(5,10)
        self.expgain = random.randint(9,15)
GoblinIG = Goblin("Goblin")

class Skeleton:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 25
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(2,7)
        self.goldgain = random.randint(0,10)
        self.expgain = random.randint(5,10)
SkeletonIG = Skeleton("Skeleton")

class Colbolt:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 50
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(7,15)
        self.goldgain = random.randint(10,20)
        self.expgain = random.randint(9,20)
ColboltIG = Colbolt("Colbolt")

# Functions

# Start Up Prompt
def main():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("Basic Text RPG game.\nCreated on July 24, 2018.\n\n")
    print ("Select an option\n")
    print ("1.) Start")
    print ("2.) Load")
    print ("3.) Exit")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == "start":
        start()
    elif option == "load":
        if os.path.exists("savefile") == True:
            os.system('clear')
            with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:
                global PlayerIG
                PlayerIG = pickle.load(f)
            print ("Loaded Save State...\n")
            option = raw_input
            start1()
        else:
            print ("You have no save file for this game.")
            option = raw_input
            main()
    elif option == "exit":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print ("Error 404: Unknown command")
        main()

# Goining User Infomation
def start():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("Hello, what is your name?")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    global PlayerIG
    PlayerIG = Player(option)
    start1()

# Main Page - What The User Chooses To Do
def start1():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("Name: %s" % PlayerIG.name)
    print ("Experience: %i" % PlayerIG.exp)
    print ("Attack: %i" % PlayerIG.attack)
    print ("Gold: %d" % PlayerIG.gold)
    print ("Current Weapons: %s" % PlayerIG.curweap)
    print ("Health Potions: %d" % PlayerIG.pots_health)
    print ("Health: %i/%i\n" % (PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.maxhealth))
    print ("1.) Fight")
    print ("2.) Drink Health Potion")
    print ("3.) Shop")
    print ("4.) Save")
    print ("5.) Inventory")
    print ("6.) Exit")
    os.system('clear')
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == "fight":
        os.system('clear')
        prefight()
    elif option == "shop":
        shop()
    elif option == "drink health potion":
        drinkpot_health_startpage()
    elif option == "drink health":
        drinkpot_health_startpage()
    elif option == "health potion":
        drinkpot_health_startpage()
    elif option == "save":
        os.system('clear')
        with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(PlayerIG, f)
            print ("\nGame has been saved!\n")
        option = raw_input
        start1()
    elif option == "exit":
        sys.exit()
    elif option == "inventory":
        inventory()
    else:
        print ("\n")
        start1()

# Accessing The Inventory Of The User
def inventory():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("What do you want to do?")
    print ("1.) Equip Weapon")
    print ("2.) Exit")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == "equip weapon":
        equip()

    elif option == "exit":
        start1()

    else:
        os.system('clear')
        print ("Error 404: Unknown Command\n")
        inventory()

# Equiping Gear
def equip():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("What do you want to equip?\n")
    for weapon in PlayerIG.weap:
        print (weapon.title())
    print ("Back")
    print ("Exit")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == PlayerIG.curweap:
        print ("You already have that weapon equipped\n")
        option = raw_input
        equip()
    elif option == "back":
        inventory()
    elif option == "exit":
        start1()
    elif option in PlayerIG.weap:
        PlayerIG.curweap = option
        print ("You have equipped %s." % option, "\n")
        option = raw_input
        equip()
    else:
        print ("You don't have %s in your inventory" % option, "\n")
        equip()

## Deciding Monster Spawn Type
def prefight():
    global enemy
    if PlayerIG.exp <= 50:
        enemynum = random.randint(1, 2)
        if enemynum == 1:
            enemy = GoblinIG
        if enemynum == 2:
            enemy = SkeletonIG
        fight()
    if PlayerIG.exp >= 50 <= 100: 
        enemynum = random.randint(1, 3)
        if enemynum == 1:
            enemy = GoblinIG
        elif enemynum == 2:
            enemy = SkeletonIG
        else:
            enemy = ColboltIG
        fight()

# Determining What The User Wants To Do
def fight():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("%s     vs      %s" % (PlayerIG.name, enemy.name))
    print ("%s's Health: %d/%d    %s's Health: %i/%i" % (PlayerIG.name, PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.maxhealth, enemy.name, enemy.health, enemy.maxhealth))
    print ("Health Potions %i\n" % PlayerIG.pots_health)
    print ("1.) Attack")
    print ("2.) Drink Health Potion")
    print ("3.) Run")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == "attack":
        os.system('clear')
        attack()
    elif option == "run":
        run()
    elif option == "drink heatlh potion":
        drinkpot_health_fightpage()
    elif option == "drink heatlh":
        drinkpot_health_fightpage()
    elif option == "heatlh potion":
        drinkpot_health_fightpage()
    else:
        print ("What the hell does that mean?")
        fight()

# Calculating Attacking Statistics + Running Fight Outcomes
def attack():
    PAttack = int(random.uniform(PlayerIG.attack // 2, PlayerIG.attack))
    EAttack = int(random.uniform(enemy.attack // 2, enemy.attack))
    if PAttack <= PlayerIG.attack // 2:
        print ("You miss!")
    else:
        enemy.health == PAttack
        print ("You deal %i damage!" % PAttack)
        enemy.health -= PAttack
    if enemy.health <= 1:
        win()
    os.system('clear')
    if EAttack <= enemy.attack // 2:
        print ("The enemy missed!")
    else:
        PlayerIG.health -= EAttack
        print ("The enemy deals %i damage!" % EAttack)
    if PlayerIG.health <= 0:
        dead()
    else:
        fight()

# If The User Drinks Health Potions From 'Start1()'
def drinkpot_health_startpage():
    os.system('clear')
    if PlayerIG.pots_health == 0:
        print ("You don't have any health potions!\n")
        start1()
    else:
        PlayerIG.health += 25
        if PlayerIG.health > PlayerIG.maxhealth:
            PlayerIG.health = PlayerIG.maxhealth
        print ("You drank a health potion!\n")
        PlayerIG.pots_health -= 1
        start1()

# If The User Drinks Health Potions From 'Fight()'
def drinkpot_health_fightpage():
    os.system('clear')
    if PlayerIG.pots_health == 0:
        print ("You don't have any health potions!\n")
        fight()
    else:
        PlayerIG.health += 25
        if PlayerIG.health > PlayerIG.maxhealth:
            PlayerIG.health = PlayerIG.maxhealth
        print ("You drank a health potion!\n")
        PlayerIG.pots_health -= 1
        fight()

# Calcualting And Running Statistics If The User Runs      
def run():
    os.system('clear')
    runnum = random.randint(1, 5)
    if runnum <= 3:
        print ("You have successfully ran away!")
        os.system('clear')
        start1()
    else:
        print ("You failed to get away!")
        os.system('clear')
        EAttack = random.randint(enemy.attack // 2, enemy.attack)
        if EAttack == enemy.attack/2:
            print ("The enemy missed!")
        else:
            PlayerIG.health -= EAttack
            print ("The enemy deals %i damage!" % EAttack)
        fight()
        if PlayerIG.health <= 0:
            dead()
        else:
            fight()

# When User Defeats Monster - Calculates What User Gained
def win():
    os.system('clear')
    enemy.health = enemy.maxhealth
    PlayerIG.gold += enemy.goldgain
    PlayerIG.exp += enemy.expgain
    print ("You have defeated the %s" % enemy.name)
    print ("You gained %i experience points!" % enemy.expgain)
    print ("You found %i gold!" % enemy.goldgain, "\n")
    start1()

# When User Dies
def dead():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("You have died\n")
    restart()

# Prompting User To Restart
def restart():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("Would you like to Restart?")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input
    if option == "yes" or "restart":
        text1 = "Restarting"
        for char in text1:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        text2 = "...\n\n"
        for char in text2:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.7)
        start()
    if option == "no":
        print ("Game Over")

# Accessing The Shop
def shop():
    os.system('clear')
    print ("Rhaast's Weapons Shop\n")
    print ("\nWhat would you like to buy?\n")
    print ("1.) Long Sword 10gp")
    print ("2.) Great Sword 40gp")
    print ("3.) Health Potion 10gp")
    print ("Back")
    print (" ")
    raw_input = input (">>> ")
    option = raw_input

    if option in weapon1:
        if PlayerIG.gold >= weapon1[option]:
            os.system('clear')
            PlayerIG.gold -= weapon1[option]
            PlayerIG.weap.append(option)
            print ("You have bought %s!" % option, "\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()
        else:
            os.system('clear')
            print ("You don't have enough gold\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()

    if option in weapon2:
        if PlayerIG.gold >= weapon2[option]:
            os.system('clear')
            PlayerIG.gold -= weapon2[option]
            PlayerIG.weap.append(option)
            print ("You have bought %s!" % option, "\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()
        else:
            os.system('clear')
            print ("You don't have enough gold\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()

    if option in healthpot:
        if PlayerIG.gold >= healthpot[option]:
            os.system('clear')
            PlayerIG.gold -= healthpot[option]
            PlayerIG.pots_health += 1
            print("You have bought %s!" % option, "\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()
        else:
            os.system('clear')
            print ("You don't have enough gold\n")
            option = raw_input
            shop()

    elif option == "back":
        start1()

    else:
        os.system('clear')
        print ("That item does not exist\n")
        option = raw_input
        shop()

##__main__##
main()
```

Comment: What are `PlayerIG` and `enemy`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code merely defines a class and a function, then quits -- nothing ever gets called, as you have no main program.

Comment: Also, there appears to be only the one goblin in the world, `GoblinIG`.  If you want to reset or revive the same goblin for each encounter, then write code to do so.  If you want to have different goblins, then instantiate a new goblin for each encounter.  Without your MCVE, we can't really tell how you want this to work.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion my man, I was unable to. post the entire code due to the space it would use, but the rundown is that I use 'PlayerIG' and 'enemy' as a clearer way to distinguish them from each other further into the code. 'PlayerIG' relates to the User's information whereas 'enemy' relates to the Goblin's information. Let me know if this cleared up your question.

Comment: Also, you might want to perform the expected research before proceeding with this posting.  There are many combat programs on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  If your purpose is to get a working system (rather than executing a programming exercise), you should adapt one of those.  My first such system is about 40 years old.

Comment: Again, **MCVE**.  You post the *minimal* code needed to illustrate the problem.  Dumping your entire application is an equally sure way to get your posting closed.  Stack Overflow is to serve as a reference for other programmers; fixing *one* person's problem is merely a side effect.  :-)

Comment: Alright mates sorry about that I have attached my entire code as of now. I hope you can see the issue. I have tried to use 'def reset(self): __init__(self)' but that only resulted in a trackback error.